# Cannot perform @Autowired a bean on integration Test for SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, integration-testing, war

I have an application on SpringBoot 2.x

```java
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class WebSpringBootJarApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebSpringBootJarApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(WebSpringBootJarApplication.class);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>weblogic.war.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>weblogic-war-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>weblogic-war-spring-boot</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
```

This is the class that should be autowired...

```java
@Service
public class CompanyReadServiceImpl implements CompanyReadService {

    private CompanyMapper companyMapper;

    private CompanyReadRepository companyReadRepository;


    @Autowired
    public CompanyReadServiceImpl(CompanyMapper companyMapper,
                                  CompanyReadRepository companyReadRepository) {
        this.companyMapper = companyMapper;
        this.companyReadRepository = companyReadRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public CompanyDto getById(Long id) {

        Company company = find(id);

        return transform(company);
    }


    @Transactional
    @Override
    public boolean isByName(String name) {
        return this.companyReadRepository.findByName(name).isPresent();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public CompanyDto getByName(String name) {

        Company company = companyReadRepository.findByName(name).orElse(new Company());

        return transform(company);

    }

    private Company find(Long id){

       return this.companyReadRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found"));
    }

    private CompanyDto transform(Company company){

        return this.companyMapper.companyToCompanyDto(company);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
```

**update**

This class is from similar project and It work (but Intellij idea mark the fields as mistakes)

in the **src/test/java/weblogic/war/spring/boot/service/read/CompanyReadServiceTest.java**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CompanyReadServiceTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompanyReadServiceTest.class);

    private static String NAME_METHOD_READ_BY_NAME_BOOLEAN = "isByName";

    @Autowired
    private CompanyReadRepository companyReadRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CompanyReadService companyReadService;

    @Autowired
    private CompanyReadRepositoryTest companyReadRepositoryTest;

    @Autowired
    private CompanyMapper companyMapper;

    @Test
    public void getById() {

        Company lastEntry = getLastEntry();

        Long idExpected = null;
        if(lastEntry != null) idExpected = lastEntry.getId();

        if(idExpected != null){

            CompanyDto companyDto = searchByIdEntry(idExpected);
            Long idActual = companyDto.getId();

            Assert.assertEquals("Lookup of entry - failed!!!", idExpected, idActual );
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void isByName() {

        Company lastEntry = getLastEntry();

        String name = null;
        if(lastEntry != null) name = lastEntry.getName();


        if(name != null){
            boolean entryByName = isEntryByName(name);
            Assert.assertTrue("Lookup of entry - failed", entryByName);
        }
    }


    private CompanyDto searchByIdEntry(Long id){

        return this.companyReadService.getById(id);
    }


    private boolean isEntryByName(String name){

        return getByNameReflection(companyReadService, NAME_METHOD_READ_BY_NAME_BOOLEAN, name);
    }


    private Company getLastEntry() {

        Optional<Company> lastEntry = companyReadRepositoryTest.getLastEntry();

        return lastEntry.orElse(null);
    }


}
```

I make a copy a project.

**update_2**

I cleared the local Maven storage.
The IDE also (at compile time ) highlights fields that are presumably not automatically connected. but I run a test class and it works ...

Why? (This may have started when I just renamed the package and edited the pom.xml)

Autowiring occur good in working scope  the app. but It doesn't work in testing scope the app.

Who can share ideas on this issue ?

Comment: Do you have a [spring-boot-starter-test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing) starter? So you are getting a NullPointerException for `companySaveService`, correct?

Comment: Iitellij IDE have pointed me on mistake. So test doesn't work

Comment: Gimby, in the test class, I can connect any bean, regardless of where it is located and it should connect. This is what I do often in integration tests

Comment: Boris, That's right. not even null, but at the compilation stage, the development environment indicates an error...

Comment: I deleted the class so that it wouldn't confuse you...

Comment: Are those tests under the same "root" package as your main application class (WebSpringBootJarApplication)?

Comment: Also is any exception thrown?

Comment: There are no exceptions. Both classes (from the application area and the testApp area) are located in the same packages. But they work.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to load actual application context for Junit purpose. 
you can do that using below Where WebSpringBootJarApplication class is the original Spring context

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebSpringBootJarApplication.class})
public class HelloWorldTest {

@Autowired(required = true)
SomeService service;

@Test
public void helloTest() {
    System.out.println(service);
}
}
```